# Laravel - Best way to correct the url on every request?

Tags: php, laravel, slug

what is the best way to correct the url in specific models? I have few models with a slug and the url schema is:

```
Route::get('/abc/{id}/{slug?}', 'AbcController@show')->name('abc.show');
Route::get('/abc/{id}/{slug?}/def-show', 'AbcDefController@show')->name('abc.def.show');
Route::get('/abc/{id}/{slug?}/def', 'AbcDefController@create')->name('abc.def.create');
```

On every controller I'm asking it like this:

```
if ($slug !== $abc->slug) {
    return redirect()->to(route([controller-function-specific], [$abc->id, $abc->slug]));
}

return view('[blade-template]', compact(['abc']))->withCanonical($abc->slug);
```

What is the better approach? I tried it with observers ("retrieved") but I don't need that for every function/action in the controller (e. g. "index" which only lists all elements and doesnt need slug) and also the route is different.

My solution works but it's redundant because I insert this specific part in a lot functions/actions. I could write it into the model but this doesn't solve the redundant calling like checkSlug('[ROUTE]').

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not require the slug? There are packages for this: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable

Comment: Because I don't want to search for a slug in database. The slug is just for nicer url and if someone enters "[url]/news/1/hello-w" or even "[url]/news/1", then the user should see "[url]/news/1/hello-world". The id is necessary and I just searching for id.

Comment: You're searching the database in either scenario. In one case, you're looking up by ID. In the other, you're looking up by slug. Same impact on the DB. (In fact, your redirect approach means you're doing the lookups *twice*.)

Comment: I don't searching the database by slug. I searching by ID and selecting the slug column. Anyway I would have the same problem because a url like "[url]/news/1/hello-w" would not work and this is not my intention. I want to fix the url as much as possible.